# ASP.NET MVC Html.CheckBoxListFor is missing / compiler error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a list of checkbox items for a legacy ASP.NET MVC application.

Like [this](https://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc/) and [this](https://www.compilemode.com/2015/10/bind-checkbox-list-for-in-asp-net-mvc.html).

Given the following code, I get the following error:

```
<td>@if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => new[] { "yo" }, new[] { "hi" } );
    }
</td>
```

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is missing / unable to be found?

When I click F12 on `Html` in the code, this is the assembly/version of MVC:

[image]

- project is .NET Full Framework 4.8
- MVC = nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` 5.2.7

Furthermore, when I try searching for `CheckBoxListFor` in the MS docs, there's nothing returned. When i search for `CheckBoxFor` there are results.

So does `CheckBoxListFor` even exist any more for ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Try `Install-Package MvcCheckBoxList`. [This extension is no longer supported, no new versions are being developed or planned to be released.](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not supported anymore on MVC 5.